# Delphi TImage Over A TSpeedButton

Tags: delphi, button, transparent, visible, timage

I want to put a TButton or TSpeedButton over top of a TImage and make the button transparent so you can still click it, but you see the image rather than the button. I can't seem to get this to work though, I changed the TSpeedButton to transparent, but it didn't seem to do anything.

I also tried making Visible false for the button, but then it becomes unclickable. Is there a way to make a button invisible without losing its functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this ? You can simply handle the `OnClick` event of your `TImage`.

Comment: Your text question describes the opposite of the title. What's correct?

Comment: Both, @Jachguate. The button should be on top of the image for handling clicks, but the image should be on top for painting.

Comment: @Rob you can have only one in top of the other, IMHO transparency is a different thing.

Comment: Why cannot u use TSpeedButton.Glyph and TButton.Glyph ?

Comment: Right, @Jachguate. The user wants the *visual* effect equivalent to an image on top of a button, but the *interactive* effect equivalent to a button on top of an image. Although you and I know that TImage and TSpeedButton don't work that way, it was not apparent to User. Hence, this question. Transparency seems relevant, if you think that making a button transparent would allow you to have something that reacts to click events yet doesn't obscure the image.

Comment: Putting a glyph on a button doesn't hide the button, @Arioch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a button. Delete it and handle the image's OnClick event instead.

If you need to know the point on the image that was clicked, call GetMessagePos from your event handler.

Comment: Good! Seems he doesn't the buttons animation anyway (or he wouldn't try make the button invisible).

Comment: +1 For `GetMessagePos` which is handy, I was unaware of its existence.

Comment: Alternatively, use the `OnMouseDown` event and have it save the provided X,Y coordinates somewhere for the `OnClick` event to use.

Comment: @Remy Well, surely that's a worse option than GetMessagePos

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Not necessarily. `GetMessagePos()` returns the screen coordinates of the mouse when the last message retreived by `GetMessage()` was created. Such messages are queued, so by the time the `OnClick` event is triggered, the `TImage` might have moved to different screen coordinates. Also, the `OnClick` event might not be message-driven (ie, `TImage.Click()` was called in code). `OnMouseDown` does not suffer from the screen coordinates issue. The provided coordinates are relative to the `TImage's` client area, thus always the same regardless of where the `TImage` moves onscreen.

Comment: @Remy That's rather bizarre. MouseDown is the wrong event for a button click. It fires when the mouse goes up. What kind of interface has the click target moving around? Do you do that or see that a lot? Do you really think that mouse down is in general better here than GetMessagePos?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, "_What kind of interface has the click target moving around?_": a lot of the touch UIs are doing this if your MouseUp position is not the same as the MouseDown one (or rather FingerUp...).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't say to use `OnMouseDown` as a click event, merely to save the TImage-relative coordinates for use in the actual `OnClick` event. `OnMouseDown` will always occur first. And yes, I think using `OnMouseDown` is more reliable for processing mouse positions than using `GetMessagePos()`. Otherwise, use `TMouse.CursorPos` and `TControl.ScreenToClient()` inside the `OnClick` event itself.

Comment: @Remy Try pressing down on a button, moving off the button, and releasing mouse

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: releasing the mouse while it is not over the control will not generate an `OnClick` event (I tried it with both `TImage` and `TButton`). The mouse has to remain on top of the control during both MouseDown and MouseUp actions to generate a click.

Comment: @Remy So shouldn't you prefer mouse up to mouse down then?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `OnMouseUp` is triggered after `OnClick`.